# Safely delete some Starcraft 2 files?

Tags: starcraft-2

Starcraft 2 is taking up so much space in my drive. I was wondering if there are some files which can be safely deleted?

Comment: depends are you still planning on playing the game? you can delete some files but they'll be redownloaded the next time you open the game

Answer (score 2):

The only safe files are your saved games.

Files are created by a person.  It is very unlikely for them to make random files that isn't essential.  You can probably delete some configuration files, but those don't take up much space.

The issue is space, and anything that's substantially large will be required by the game.

Comment: Well that sucks, can't believe SC1 just needs less than 100MB

Comment: I can.  It's released March 31, 1998.  In 6 months it will legally be an adult.

Comment: Well, if you think of it the game-play is pretty much the same. I bet SC2 today can be optimized, however that doesn't seem to be a priority which is evident from the massive lag and performance issue on patch 3.0.

Comment: I don't have massive lag on patch 3.0. It could have been a number of different issues that you were facing.